# How to close background programs macOS in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash-scripting

I am attempting to learn to use Bash scripts, and have encountered a weird error.

I opened a terminal and ran an npm program using the following command:

```
node index.js &
```

This is running a express.js API that I can use in a UI I am making.

After this I closed and Quit the terminal,

But when I open postman, My api is still running!

It doesn't show up when I use $ ps or $ jobs.

How do I find and close this program?

p.s. I'm using the latest version of Mac OS.
p.p.s. I'm sorry if this question has already been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to kill the process after quitting the terminal**

You have various options, but the easiest one that shuts down all `node` processes is:

```
killall node
```

Or, get a list of processes with `ps -ef` and find the one you want to kill:

```
ps -ef | grep "node" | grep -v grep
```

Just running `ps` will not be enough. The PID will be shown in the second column, so run:

```
kill <pid>
```

Where `<pid>` is the process ID.

**What to do instead of `&`**

If you want to have a program running all the time while developing, such as a web server, you can use tools such as [`forever`](https://github.com/foreversd/forever). These are made for running programs in the background (with optional parameters), which you can also easily stop again.

Comment: Thanks, I had a co-worker do the same steps right after I posted this question. But it is good to know.